# Using `Set` Argument to Scala Code in Java

Tags: java, scala

I'm trying to call my Scala `Util` object from Java code:

**Main.java**

```
Set<Long> items = new HashSet<Long>();
// fill up items with Long
MyUtil.foo(100, items);
```

**Util.scala**

```
object Foo {
 type Id = Long
 def foo(id: Id, items: scala.collection.mutable.Set[Id])
```

Here's the compile-time error:

```
  could not parse error message:   
  required: long,scala.collection.mutable.Set<Object>
  found: Long,java.util.Set<Long>
  reason: actual argument java.util.Set<Long> cannot be converted to 
      scala.collection.mutable.Set<Object> by method invocation conversion`
```

From reading these Java to Scala Collections [docs](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.JavaConversions%24), I am using a `mutable` Set rather than the default, immutable Set:

`scala.collection.mutable.Set <=> java.util.Set`

But, I don't understand the error message. By using a `Long` (boxed `long`) in my Java code, why is a `Set<Long>` found?

Comment: Those conversion work as far as I understand while in `.scala`. Java can not cast from class A to B like that.

Comment: why the down-vote? is this problem really that simple?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Demonstrating what the commenter said:

```
scala> import collection.JavaConverters._
import collection.JavaConverters._

scala> val js = (1 to 10).toSet.asJava
js: java.util.Set[Int] = [5, 10, 1, 6, 9, 2, 7, 3, 8, 4]

scala> def f(is: collection.mutable.Set[Int]) = is.size
f: (is: scala.collection.mutable.Set[Int])Int

scala> def g(js: java.util.Set[Int]) = f(js.asScala)
g: (js: java.util.Set[Int])Int

scala> g(js)
res0: Int = 10
```

Comment: Hi @som-snytt. Would `error: value toSet is not a member of java.util.Set[Long]` show up here: `foo(items: java.util.Set[Long]) { val scalaSet = items.toSet }` due to the `java.util.Set` type?

Comment: Yes. So the preferred idiom is to use JavaConverters (not Conversions), and call asJava and asScala to convert, as shown. Then in your method that takes a Java set, call asScala on it first. You could also call js.asScala.toSet to build an immutable Set.

Comment: I ran into another error that may or may not be related to this one - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21483121/calling-scala-method-from-java-setobject-or-setlong. If you get time, please take a look. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Working with *Scala collections* and type aliases from *Java code* (not the converse, as [som-snytt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1296806/som-snytt) showed :) is going to be at least nasty, most likely very painful, and quite possibly impossible.

If you're able to modify the Scala side of the API, I'd recommend adding a Java-friendlier API to it.  If not, I guess you could build an adapter layer in Scala that proxies Java clients through to the native Scala API.

So, something like:

```
// Original Scala
object Foo {
  type Id = Long
  def foo(id: Id, items: scala.collection.mutable.Set[Id]) 
}

// Java adapter -- generics might be made to work on the Java side, 
// but Long is particularly problematic, so we'll just force it here
object FooJ {
  import scala.collection.JavaConverters._

  def foo(id: Long, items: java.util.Set[Long]) = {
    Foo.foo(id, items.asScala)
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Perhaps it's obvious, but `ju.Set[Long]` is an abbreviation for `java.util.Set[Long]`?

Comment: Whoops, yeah. Fixed. :)